# How to make toolbar item in Carousel page go to other page

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a carousel page and a home icon in the toolbar. When clicking the home icon, error appears.

Code in Xaml

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="home.png" Command="{Binding HomeCommand}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Code in ViewModel

```
public class InfoItemViewModel : ObservableObject, INavigatedAware
    {
        public DelegateCommand HomeCommand { get; private set; }
        private INavigationService mNavigationService;
        public INavigationService navigationService;

        public InfoItemViewModel(int productId, INavigationService navigationService)
            : base(listenCultureChanges: true)
        {
            _productId = productId;

            mNavigationService = navigationService;
            HomeCommand = new DelegateCommand(HomeAction);

            LoadData();
        }

private async void HomeAction()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button : Home");
            await mNavigationService.NavigateAsync("DashboardMenuPage");
        }
```

Code in Xaml.cs

```
public partial class InfoItem : ContentPage
    {
        public InfoItem()
            : **this**(DataMyDOF.Products[0].Id)
        {
        }

        public InfoItem(int productId, INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new InfoItemViewModel(productId, navigationService);
        }
    }
}
```

The error 'this'

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter ‘navigationService’ of ‘InfoItem.InfoItem(int,
>   INavigationService)’

After i add navigationService in the constructor, 'this' appears error. Actually I combine the carousel code from grial with prism. Products[0].Id is the array id. Should i add the navigation as the parameter too?

I tried to use Xamarin Forms Navigation. But still there's an error.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
    public INavigation Navigation { get; }

private void HomeAction()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button : Home");
            Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new DashboardMenuPage()));
        }
```

The error

> System.NullReferenceException has been thrown Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object

Comment: Is your navigationService set to anything? In the constructor it doesn't look like this value is set so it would be null. Then mNavigationService would also be null and that would lead to your exception.

Comment: I've added navigationService in the constructor but there's error in the xaml.cs 'this'. Please help. Thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: The error is ;There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter ‘navigationService’  of ‘InfoItem.InfoItem(int, INavigationService)’. Is there any solution i can use besides navigationService to go to the other page? Or maybe I can put all the codes in xaml.cs to my viewmodel?

Comment: The error is because in your constructor for InfoItem() with no parameters, you tell it to call the constructor which takes an int id.  However, you haven't created such constructor so that is the error.

Comment: I found other solution without using NavigationService. I use Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DashboarMenuPage()); and it goes to my dashboard. Thank you very much for the help and replies.